# Excel function sheet gives errors

Tags: excel, function

My first attempt at user-defined functions in Excel (Mac) isn't going well. This gives "function or sub undefined":

```
Function CylArea(d0 As Double, theta As Double, y As Double) As Double
    CylArea = Pi() * (d0 ^ 2 / 4 + d0 * Tan(Radians(theta)) * y + Tan(Radians(theta)) ^ 2 * y ^ 2)
End Function

Function CylVolume(d0 As Double, theta As Double, y As Double) As Double
    CylVolume = Pi() * (d0 ^ 2 / 4 * y + 1 / 2 * d0 * Tan(Radians(theta)) * y ^ 2 + 1 / 3 * Tan(Radians(theta)) ^ 2 * y ^ 3)
End Function

Function CylAreaDeriv(d0 As Double, theta As Double, y As Double) As Double
    CylAreaDeriv = Pi() * (d0 * Tan(Radians(theta)) + 2 * Tan(Radians(theta)) ^ 2 * y)
End Function
```

Curiously, the `Pi` in `CylVolume` is highlighted.

Comment: I am not on my mac so I can't test, but does changing `Pi()` to `WorksheetFunction.Pi` help?  It seems to me the code is expecting a function or subroutine named `Pi`.

Comment: I changed it and now it doesn't give an error message, it just gives the wrong answer (0.0000):  Public Function CylVolume(d0, theta, y)
CylVolume = WorksheetFunction.Pi() * (d0 ^ 2 / 4 * y + 1 / 2 * d0 * WorksheetFunction.Tan(WorksheetFunction.Radians(theta)) * y ^ 2 + 1 / 3 * WorksheetFunction.Tan(WorksheetFunction.Radians(theta)) ^ 2 * y ^ 3)
End Function

Comment: In addition to `WorksheetFunction.Pi` try changing `Tan` to `Math.Tan` and try changing `Radians` to `WorksheetFunction.Radians`.  I will add as an answer for readability.

Comment: Whoops, spoke too soon. Now it highlights ".Tan" and gives me the undefined message. I am not accustomed to being this lost! Is it just me or is this process of creating a simple function incredibly convoluted?

Comment: Hallelujah! the "Math.Tan" fixed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I added this as an answer too and I'd appreciate it if you'd accept it.  Glad you're up and running!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to use Excel functions as you would in a worksheet within VBA code.  This will likely not work.

Try changing all instances of `Pi()` to `WorksheetFunction.Pi`, all instances of `Tan` to `Math.Tan` and all instances of `Radians` to `WorksheetFunction.Radians` so that the code looks more like this:

```
Function CylVolume(d0 As Double, theta As Double, y As Double) As Double
    CylVolume = WorksheetFunction.Pi * (d0 ^ 2 / 4 * y + 1 / 2 * d0 * Math.Tan(WorksheetFunction.Radians(theta)) * y ^ 2 + 1 / 3 * Math.Tan(WorksheetFunction.Radians(theta)) ^ 2 * y ^ 3)
End Function
```

Comment: Am I crazy, or would it be reasonable to think that Excel might be able to do this on its own? I'm having better luck using AppleScript with Excel than its own native VBA language.

Comment: No, you're not crazy.  I think an implicit `WorksheetFunction` or `Math` in front of those functions would make sense so you don't have to worry about these things.